# Change the value of spin button

Tags: c, widget, gtk, glade, gtk2

I'm making a gtk2 application from scratch using Glade3 and with my own main C file.

Scenario is like this.
There's a collection of 3 spin buttons. I need to change the value of the 3rd spin button in real time when the value in spin button 1 or 2 changes.

With Glade3 I've made those 3 spin buttons and I know how to read values when they are changing with the following handler.

```
void value_calc(GtkSpinButton *o, gpointer d)
{
    gdouble x = gtk_spin_button_get_value (o);
    printf("spin-button1-vlaue: %f\n", x);
}
```

I connected the "change value" signal of the 1st spin button with above `value_calc` handler. It is successfully printing the changed values.
I've done the same thing to the 2nd spin button.
I have all two values and now I need to update the value of 3rd spin button.

```
void set_values (gdouble value_to_be_added)
{
    GtkSpinButton *spinbuton_3;
    gtk_spin_button_set_value (spinbuton_3, value_to_be_added);
}
```

When compiling above no errors and warnings. But when run the program and changing the values of spin buttons, some error throws to command line.

```
Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_spin_button_set_value: assertion 'GTK_IS_SPIN_BUTTON (spin_button)' failed
```

Also it doesn't perform the required action.

Comment: The `spinbuton_3` in `set_values()` is local to `set_values()`; it is not the same `spinbuton_3` that is outside that function or in another function. And by default, local variables have no defined value, so you're just passing a random pointer to `gtk_spin_button_set_value()`. You need to pass `spinbuton_3` into `set_values()` somehow. (Also I am not sure if it is a good idea to mix Glade 3 with GTK+ 2.)

Comment: @andlabs Thanks for pointing me out a critical mistake. Also can you explain me how to pass the spinbuton_3 into set_values() ?
(also Glade3 is for gtk+ 2 development and Glade is for gtk+ 3 development)

Comment: Ah, okay then. You pass `spinbox_3` as a parameter to `set_values()`, just like the two parameters to `value_calc()` above that.

Comment: @andlabs well this is kind of a egg-chicken problem. `set_values()` is called inside the `value_calc()` so inside the `value_calc` there's no reference to the `spinbutton_3` to pass to `set_value()`

Comment: The `gpointer` argument at the end of every signal function was designed for this case. The value is the last argument to your `g_signal_connect()`. You can pass `spinbox_3` there, or you can allocate a structure to hold all your widget pointers.

Comment: @andlabs Yes. That worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: @andlabs Also do you have any idea, if I'm making a structure of widgets, which will point to each widget, since I built the interface/widgets with Glade, how can I possibly point to widgets on the Glade interface?

Comment: Do you mean automatically filling in the structure? If so, then IDK, sorry.